# Do I need to reset SQLiteOpenHelper version to 1 before publishing

Tags: android, sqlite

My app uses **sqlite**. While writing it I've been incrementing the version number as I went along modifying the tables. The app is almost done and am ready to publish it on play.

Do I need to reset the version number to 1 before publishing ? Is there anyway I can reset the current db values on my phone to check if its working fine. (I'm publishing it with no preset values, it's up to the user to fill as needed. Currently I have all the entries I added to check if its working fine.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't published the app before, you can have any database version you want. It is just a number. No one (other than you) has your database files with any version numbers yet.

When you publish an upgrade to a published app, then you'll have to be more careful with the version number: make sure your database helper `onUpgrade()` helper can migrate user data and table schemas from any previously published version.

Comment: To extend the answer: you need to consider the cases when the user skipped some update versions of your app and the difference of DB versions between what the user has and latest version is higher than one. For example if the user is making an upgrade of the app and the DB is now at version 5, while the previous DB version was 1, then the application needs to perform the update from 5 to 1. Makes sense?